# Phpdesktop chrome not loading fonts

Tags: php, angular, google-chrome, phpdesktop

Im building a php desktop chrome app with Laravel8 at back and angular/ionic up front/ It working well but php desktop isnt loading my google font over the network and im not sure why:
my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Ionic App</title>

  <base href="/" />
  
  <link href = "assets/google-font.css" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/icon/favicon.png" />

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

google-font.css is as follows:

```
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1MmgVxFIzIFKw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1MmgVxMIzIFKw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1MmgVxEIzIFKw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1MmgVxLIzIFKw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1MmgVxHIzIFKw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1MmgVxGIzIFKw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1MmgVxIIzI.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

The src urls in google font dont load in php desktop chrome but run fine in the browser, what is going on?
---------------------EDIT----------------------
Ok, after further trouble shooting ive discovered php desktop chrome will not load an asset that is served over a network
e.g

```
<link href = "http://www.test.com/test.css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
```

The above will fail to load, is this a problem with chrome, how can i correct it?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you can bundle the styles in your Angular app.

In `angular.json` find the "styles" property (the first one not the test one although you can add to both) which has an array value.

Add this:

```
"styles": [
  "src/assets/google-font.css"
  "src/styles.scss"
]
```

Obviously, make sure to add the file to the assets folder.

You can remove the entry from `index.html`.